# State not updating with assigned constant with useSelector in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have within my functional component:

```
   const selectedHotel = useSelector(state => state.selectedHotel)
          const dispatch = useDispatch()
    

const handleHotelSelectChange = (event) =>{
  console.log("DISPatching...", selectedHotel, event.target.childNodes[event.target.selectedIndex].id)
  dispatch(changeSelectedHotel(event.target.childNodes[event.target.selectedIndex].id))  
}

const handleAutoHotelSelect = (event) => {
 console.log("DISPatching...", selectedHotel, event, event)
 dispatch(changeSelectedHotel(event))  
}
```

And the reducer looks like this:

```
export const configHotelReducer = function (state = "all" , action) {
  console.log("REDUCER", state, action)
    switch (action.type) {
      case "SELECT_HOTEL":
        return action.payload;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

in

```
  console.log("DISPatching...", selectedHotel, event.target.childNodes[event.target.selectedIndex].id)
```

I can see `selectedHotel` is always undefined, but in:

```
  console.log("REDUCER", state, action)
```

I can see how it updates with every dispatch, how can I do for `selectedHotel` to return the updated state?

---

this is how my action looks like:

```
import {SELECT_HOTEL} from './constants'

export const changeSelectedHotel = (id) => {
    console.log({type: SELECT_HOTEL,  payload: id, })
    
    return ({
    type: SELECT_HOTEL,
    payload: id,
}) }
```

Comment: Can you share what you do in `changeSelectedHotel` looks like `return action.payload;` is the problem but I want to make sure

Comment: You can try setting the action with `event.target.value` in React events are usually "garbage collected" so it's not a good idea to try and save them for later use and these events are not [serializable](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state) so you should not save them in redux state.

Comment: You should also look in the redux devtools and add relevant information you see there to your question.

Comment: I have updated with `changeSelectedHotel` code @SinanYaman

Comment: The problem is I don't want the value of the options in select, but it's ID, but i don't want to show the id's in the options @HMR

Comment: I have redux devtools, but is shown as disabled in my explorer, no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it and how to add redux devtools to your code:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {
  hotels: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Hotel One' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Hotel Two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Hotel Three' },
  ],
  selectedHotel: undefined,
};
//action types
const SELECT_HOTEL_1 = 'SELECT_HOTEL_1';
const SELECT_HOTEL_2 = 'SELECT_HOTEL_2';
//action creators
const setHotel1 = (hotel) => ({
  type: SELECT_HOTEL_1,
  payload: hotel,
});
const setHotel2 = (hotelId) => ({
  type: SELECT_HOTEL_2,
  payload: hotelId,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === SELECT_HOTEL_1) {
    return {
      ...state,
      selectedHotel: payload,
    };
  }
  //other way of selecting hotel, logic is in reducer
  //  this would be the better way but you need hotels
  //  in state
  if (type === SELECT_HOTEL_2) {
    return {
      ...state,
      selectedHotel: state.hotels.find(
        ({ id }) => id === payload
      ),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectHotels = (state) => state.hotels;
const selectSelectedHotel = (state) => state.selectedHotel;
//simple thunk implementation
const thunk = ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (
  action
) =>
  typeof action === 'function'
    ? action(dispatch, getState)
    : next(action);
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
const App = () => {
  const hotels = useSelector(selectHotels);
  const hotel = useSelector(selectSelectedHotel);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const change = React.useCallback(
    (e) =>
      dispatch(
        setHotel1(
          hotels.find(
            ({ id }) => id === Number(e.target.value)
          )
        )
      ),
    [dispatch, hotels]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        select hotel 1
        <select
          // cannot use hotel?.id because SO babel is too old
          value={hotel && hotel.id}
          onChange={change}
        >
          <option>Select a hotel</option>
          {hotels.map((hotel) => (
            <option key={hotel.id} value={hotel.id}>
              {hotel.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        select hotel 2
        <select
          // cannot use hotel?.id because SO babel is too old
          value={hotel && hotel.id}
          onChange={(e) =>
            dispatch(setHotel2(Number(e.target.value)))
          }
        >
          <option>Select a hotel</option>
          {hotels.map((hotel) => (
            <option key={hotel.id} value={hotel.id}>
              {hotel.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It worked for the devtools, I can see it activated now, anyhow, the state does not update still, now it only sets to the default state on the first render and when it changes it switches to undefined

Comment: it works, I was not setting well the state in redux and namespacing it correctly